# Is it permitted to work as a freelancer on Upwork while studying in Germany?

Tags: germany, taxes, student-visa, freelance, self-employment

Next April I am going to start a master program in Germany living on a student visa.

Currently I am working as a freelancer on Upwork. I know that in Germany it is [not permitted for people on student visas to work as freelancers](https://www.daad.de/deutschland/in-deutschland/arbeit/en/9148-side-jobs/), but, to the best of my knowledge, it only applies if the source/destination of income is Germany.

In my case, the source of my income would be Poland and the destination would be Egypt. Does this prohibition apply to me?

Comment: Dual post: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27038/is-it-permitted-to-work-as-a-freelancer-on-upwork-while-studying-in-germany

Comment: That's true. I asked it over there and some users pointed I should ask it here for answers :)

Comment: You might want to find some german-specific law forum (likely in German), because your question is a very specific niche about German laws. Or pay for info session with knowledgeable German layer/accountant.